# JAVA println gives unexpected output

Tags: java

I have problem with JAVA code, that is I have a code:

```
class test {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        while( x < 5 ){
           y = y - x;
           System.out.print(x + "" + y + " ");
           x += 1;
        }

       }
}
```

and I compile it in Command Prompt and I get this:

```
00 1-1 2-3 3-6 4-10
```

Where I expected output to be:

```
00 11 23 36 210
```

I don't know where the problem is.

Thanks for any responses.

Comment: Why would you expect `210` in the output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-` in `y = y - x;` means subtraction.

Most likely you intended

```
y = y + x;
```

or

```
y += x;
```

Also most likely you expected.

```
00 11 23 36 410
```

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis sorry, I will try to slow down.I click on `[java]` tag to get the latest questions.

Answer (score 1):

the hyphen you see is not a hyphen but rather minus sign as `y` eventually becomes negative (based on ur code)

one way of doing it is by changing printout to be a positive value:

```
System.out.print(x + "" + y + " ");
```

to:

```
System.out.print(x + "" + Math.abs(y) + " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `y` is producing negative values:

Your code:

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
while( x < 5 ){
   y = y - x;
   System.out.print(x + "" + y + " ");
   x += 1;
}
```

Let's try to debug it:

> first iteration `y = 0-0 = 0`
>
> second iteration `y = 0-1 = -1`
>
> third iteration `y = -1-2 = -3`
>
> fourth iteration `y = -3-3 = -6`
>
> fifth iteration `y = -6-4 = -10`

As you can see, you're basically going opposite to your expected result which is a good indication that you're using an opposite operator on some variable, in this case `y-x` should be `y+x`.

Change `y = y-x` to `y = y+x`